# SQL query and calculations; formatting query correctly to select only id

Tags: mysql, sql, gps, haversine

I have a query that selects all locations within a 30 mile radius of a GPS pt. I want to get the id's of those locations, but it's also returning the distance from the center pt.

Is there anyway to perform the distance calculation without returning it?

Query:

```
SELECT id, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(
  POWER(SIN((34.1844709 - abs(dest.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),
  2) + COS(37.7749295 * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest.lat) *
  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((-118.131809 - dest.lng) *
  pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance
FROM location dest
having distance < 30
ORDER by distance
LIMIT 30
```

Output:

```
---------------------------
id    |    distance   
---------------------------
 1    |    2.310
 2    |    2.356
 17   |    4.298
```

Query based off:
http://www.notaires.fr/sites/default/files/geo_searchjkkjkj_0.pdf

Comment: Yes, just past the calculation instead of the alias name `distance`

Comment: @juergend Of course, you'd have to put the calculation into the `ORDER BY` clause as well if you did that.  It might make more sense to wrap this in an outer query that only selects the `id` column from this result set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you just do another select on this?

```
Select id
From (SELECT id, 3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(
  POWER(SIN((34.1844709 - abs(dest.lat)) * pi()/180 / 2),
  2) + COS(37.7749295 * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(dest.lat) *
  pi()/180) * POWER(SIN((-118.131809 - dest.lng) *
  pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance
FROM location dest
having distance < 30
ORDER by distance
LIMIT 30) dst
```

Comment: `distance` is undefined in your second query.  I think the first one is the way to go.

Comment: yep, agree, actually we can repeat formula in order by, but I would go with first one, so removing second version